# Content of UITableViewCell Invisible when cell is added from another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am running into a strange problem where I am adding a UITableViewCell to another TableViewController's tableView that is not currently visible but was previously loaded. The *issue* is that the cell is added to the tableView but the cell's content is blank once i go to that view controller:

[image]

This is how the cell is being added:
[image]

**CellForRowAtIndexPath of the tableView whose cell contentView is showing up invisible:**

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

          LYRConversation *conversation = [_dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

          ConversationListCell *cell = (ConversationListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_REUSE_ID forIndexPath:indexPath];

          [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath conversation:conversation];

          return cell;

 }

-(void)configureCell:(ConversationListCell *)conversationCell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath conversation:(LYRConversation *)conversation
{
    [conversationCell updateAvatarWithUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:[self avatarStringUrlForConversation:conversation]]];
    [conversationCell updateTitle:[self titleForConversation:conversation]];
    [conversationCell updateUnreadMessageIndicator:conversation];
    NSArray *otherParticipants = [[PersistentCache sharedCache] cachedUsersForUserIDs:conversation.participants];
    conversationCell.preview.text = [((PFUser *)otherParticipants.lastObject) objectForKey:@"jobTitle"];
    [UIView updateStatusIndicatorOfConversation:otherParticipants statusIndicator:conversationCell.status];
}


-(void)updateAvatarWithUrl:(NSURL *)avatarUrl
{
    if (avatarUrl != nil) {
        downloadImageThenSetForImageView(self.avatar, avatarUrl);
    }
}

-(void)updateTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    self.title.text = title;
}

-(void)updateUnreadMessageIndicator:(LYRConversation *)conversation
{
    if (conversation.lastMessage.isUnread) {
        [_unreadMessageIndicator setImage:[ConversationListCell unreadBlue]];
    }
    else {
        [_unreadMessageIndicator setImage:[ConversationListCell unreadGray]];
    }
}

+(void)updateStatusIndicatorOfConversation:(NSArray<PFUser *> *)users statusIndicator:(UIView *)view
{
    int  statusValue = ((NSNumber *)[users.firstObject objectForKey:@"status"]).intValue;
    if (statusValue == 1) {
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor PNGInOffice];
    }
    else if(statusValue == 2){
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor PNGBusy];
    }
    else if(statusValue == 3){
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor PNGAway];
    }
}
```

This view controller is laid out using auto layout in storyboard. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Trying refreshing your table view after, data is added into datasource.

Comment: I tried that but it still shows up blank occasionally

Answer (score 0):

you must add this line will work try add
 [tableView reloadData];

Comment: It did not work :( the top most cell will still be blank.

Comment: can you share piece of code.. :) we will definitely help you.

Comment: The source files are pretty long, is there any specific code you want me to share or just both view controller implementation files?

Comment: yes please share the cellforRowatindexpath and where You are add cell to other tableview cell

Comment: I just added the cellForRowAtIndexPath, the code where I add the cell to the other table view was posted in the original post under "This is how the cell is being added: ".  Could it be an AutoResizingMask issue because I am using autolayout and did not disable the autoResizingMaskIntoConstraints property for the cell?